# apply two backgrounds under a fixed sticky footer

Tags: html, css

I am using the following basic html and css pattern (although my live code looks very different)

```
html, body {height: 100%;}

#wrap {min-height: 100%;}

#main {overflow:auto;
    padding-bottom: 150px;}  /* must be same height as the footer */

#footer {position: relative;
    margin-top: -150px; /* negative value of footer height */
    height: 150px;
    clear:both;} 

/*Opera Fix*/
body:before {
    content:"";
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    width:0;
    margin-top:-32767px;/
}

<div id="wrap">

    <div id="header">

    </div>

    <div id="main">

    </div>

</div>

<div id="footer">

</div>
```

to get a sticky footer to the bottom of my page.

I have applied two backgrounds to the body tag. One is a repeating wood texture then a shadow that goes on top. Both of these go under the footer.

It almost works, but on long pages (where you have to scroll down to see the footer) when you resize the browser window the shadow (and not the wood) creeps up the page. I have tried moving the shadow to the bottom right position but that doesnt work at all.

Here is a staging of it:
I have repeated the problem in FF and Safari
http://www.dnbsandbox.com/diablo/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this from the first line of the css:

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: i dont think you looked closely at the css. that's in there already.

Comment: I said to *remove it* @liz

Comment: sorry i am so scattered I totally didnt see the remove part. It worked a charm! i checked that you answered correctly but i cant vote up unless you edit your answer...  i will if you do... thanks! why did that do it?